# Making data class with ArrayList inside Parcelable

Tags: android, kotlin

I added Parcelable implementation for my class and get this code:

```
data class Category (val name:String, var factors:ArrayList<String>):Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            TODO("factors")) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(name)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Category> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Category {
            return Category(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Category?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand I should write method for reading data from ArrayList. I've tried to use

```
parcel.readArrayList()
```

but can not understand, how to insert String as ClassLoader. Please help me to understand, how to make this object Parcelable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following within your Constructor:

```
parcel.createStringArrayList()
```

and within `writeToParcel`:

```
parcel.writeStringList(this.mTest)
```

Just a side node: If you're using Android Studio, just let it generate the Parcelable with the Parcelable code generator Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Read Parcelable

```
    segments=new ArrayList<>();
    in.readTypedList(segments,Segments.CREATOR);
    Multi = in.readString();
```

And for writing

```
 dest.writeTypedList(segments);
 dest.writeString(Multi);
```

And it works like a charm